# Setting Kendo Showloading

Tags: cordova, kendo-mobile, telerik-appbuilder

I am trying to edit the loading symbol on my existing mobile app built in AppBuilder, written by another developer. However, I can't seem to find where the loading symbol is actually set. A variable called _kendoApp is being passed around referencing a singleton kendo.mobile.Application, which then calls showLoading() and hideLoading(), but never does the app actually set the loading animation, which is (what appears to be a gif) of a blue bubble with white stripes.

I've been looking through documentation and other questions online, but have thus far been unable to find anyone so much as mentioning the loading symbol. I understand that you can set a message and attach it to the loading property (which is also not done within our app), but is it possible to change the loading animation? Thanks,

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there are some docs on showing/hiding the loader: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/loader

Comment: Thanks, I know how to show and hide the loader, just not how to set it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read your original message closely enough. I'm not sure about changing the loading icon, other than getting into the stylesheet itself, but that's a bit of a hack.